# Using fnGetData to get entire table from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using a Datatable from datatables.net and want to be able to check if the datatable is empty in order to hide the tab that it is displayed on (if datatable is empty, hide tab). 
the datatables.net API says fnGetData - Get the data for the whole table, an individual row or an individual cell based on the provided parameters.

but when I try to use it like this:

```
if($('#table1').dataTable.fnGetData()===0) {
     $('a[href="#table1-tab"]').parent().hide();
}
```

it isn't doing anything. How am I using this incorrectly?

I also tried this:

```
console.log(myArray.length);
```

and it gives zero. but when I do:

```
if(myArray.length==0){
            $table1-tab.hide();
            $('a[href="#table1-tab"]').parent().hide();
           // $table1-tab.style.display = 'none';
           // ("#table1-tab").hide();
}
```

none of the above will hide the tab.

My html is:

```
   <div id="table1-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
           <table id="myTable" class="table table-condensed"></table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is there any data on the table? also Do `console.log($('#table1').dataTable.fnGetData())` in the console and see what you get

Comment: @dcodesmith, sometimes the table is full and sometimes it is empty depending on what data is provided by another program. that's why I need to check for when it is empty so I can "hide" the table.

Comment: Did you run the console.log I asked you to?

Comment: i console.logged it for a datatable that is empty and it didn't print anything to the console. so if the datatable is never made, how can i check that it isn't made?

Comment: I'm confused here. Do you have a datable or not?

Comment: well i guess since when the datatable is given aaData that is empty it can't create the datatable object. so the datatable object doesn't exist

Comment: just because aaData is empty doesn't mean datable object doesn't exist. Can I see you full datatable initilisation code?

Comment: Yes, I created the datatable, but it is filled dynamically. Sometimes it has 10 rows, sometimes 1, sometimes there is no data and no datatable shows up at all. I am displaying it on a page. If there is not data and the datatable doesn't show, I wanted to hide the page.

Comment: am i hiding it wrong? i added code to question.

Comment: what are you trying to hide? the table? or what?

Comment: @dcodesmith, no, I have the table on a tab. I want to hide the entire tab if the datatable is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to see some HTML syntax, if not I can't help. At least the tab container

Comment: @dcodesmith, ok hopefully i added enough clarification to my question.

Comment: $('#myTable').parents('#table1-tab').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, just implementing it in the wrong place...

```
  if(myArray.length===0){
           $('a[href="#table1-tab"]').parent().hide();
```

}

I had a condition below it that said if something else was true, to show the tab, and that part was always true. so I just had to move this to below it.